# Custom definition for word boundary for words that begin or end with non-word characters

Tags: php, regex

I have an array of words that contain strings like **"DOM"** **".Net"** and **"C++"**. I'm trying to perform whole word match for each of these strings in some text, by using the word boundary wild card. If the words are read into a variable, it would look like:

```
preg_match("/\b".preg_quote($word)."\b/",...)
```

This works fine for an example like "DOM", but not for ".Net" or "C++" because word boundary is also seen at **.** in case of .Net and is already seen at **+** in case of C++. Is there an alternative way in regular expressions in PHP to treat **.Net** or **C++** as "words" for word boundary?

Comment: Well a dot would normally be the end of a word. I think you'll need to select your words on spaces. But think of this, you want to validate **.Net** but not other dots on for example the end of a sentence..? Seems to me you need to come up with soem specific requirements on what to match and what not to match.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This cannot be done, since `\b` matches for non-word characters (`\W`).

What you could do instead is search for characters that do not match some set of characters you define to be words, as shown below:

```
preg_match("/([^a-zA-Z_.+])".preg_quote($word)."\1/",...);
```

**Edit:** Added a backrefrence, so you only need to type that sequence once.

Comment: Though what happens here is that a word with a dot on the end (ending of a sentence) would be matched **with** the dot. I Think OP needs to consider the implications (nevertheless great answer!).

Answer (score 0):

character classes... lets say you only want to do spaces and commas you would do this

```
preg_match("/[, ]".preg_quote($word)."[, ]/",...)
```